# On the download page for PlayOnLinux, what is Cosmic, Bionic, Xenial, etc.?

Tags: playonlinux

On the [download page for PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html), under the Ubuntu section, it lists a lot of different versions:

- Cosmic version
- Bionic version
- Xenial version
- Trusty version
- Saucy version
- Precise version

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but what's the difference between all these versions? I looked around on the PlayOnLinux site but I can't find anything that explains what all these names mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This are the code names of the Ubuntu releases which are supported. To put it into perspective ill list them below with their version numbers. If they are already end of life or still supported you can see on this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

- 18.10    Cosmic Cuttlefish
- 18.04    Bionic Beaver
- 16.04    Xenial Xerus
- 14.04    Trusty Tahr
- 13.10    Saucy Salamander
- 12.04    Precise Pangolin

Comment: Ah, so they were Ubuntu version names, not PlayOnLinux version names. I see!